# Can i develop a wireless/Bt app for smartphone through which i can controll the raspberry pi gpio pins?

Tags: wifi, pi-3, wireless, bluetooth, android

I wish to create a android app which will be on top or wireless/Bt protocol and could communicate with Raspberry pi. Through this i want to controll the GPIO pins on my raspberry. For eg i want to have a app on phone through which i could be able to swith of a led.
Please help in understanding if this is possible and if some resources are availabele in this area which could be used for my project.

Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at [cayenne](http://cayenne.mydevices.com)

Comment: Have you tried googling your problem? The RPi is obviously capable of sending and receiving messages, and running a full Linux operating system. There are a tremendous amount of ways such a project could be done.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible.  Break it down into parts:

1. Write an app for your mobile phone.  There are really good [getting started tutorials](https://developer.android.com/about/start.html) for Android.
2. Get the app to send messages to the Raspberry Pi over Bluetooth.  Google is your friend.  I found [this example of a project](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/05/11/android-linux-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-communication/) which does exactly that.
3. Make the commands change the state of the GPIO pins. Lots of [tutorials](http://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/) exist for how to control GPIOs.

I hope that will get you started.  If not, please let us know more about what you do or don't know.  (For example, how much programming have you done - in general, on the Pi, and for Android?)

Answer (score 0):

Note that while it **should** be possible, it currently doesn't seem to be possible with the built-in Bluetooth on an RPi 3B. Source: [Bluetooth Connection problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58362/bluetooth-connection-problem/58363)

The link everyone points to is a guy using a USB Bluetooth dongle, which is not the same thing unfortunately.