# Bluetooth Connection problem

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to connect rpi3 bluetooth module with other devices but here I would like to ask your help connecting it.

I have done so many different things and the **problem rises after `pair` and `trust` when `connect` the device**, Did anyone met this issue and got a solution or succeeded using any alternative methods? (I would like to purchase USB bluetooth dongle if it definately works but currently, I am not sure whether it would work).

In **GUI**, when pairing succeeds, UI pop up says:

```
Paired successfully, but this device has 
no services which can be used with Raspberry Pi.
```

In **terminal**:
    In `bluetoothctl` after `pair` and `trust`,

```
[bluetooth]# connect 98:D3:32:10:69:4D
Attempting to connect to 98:D3:32:10:69:4D
[CHG] Device 98:D3:32:10:69:4D Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 98:D3:32:10:69:4D Connected: no
```

**So to troubleshoot**, I did following:

dmesg:

```
[   10.442141] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.442156] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.442165] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.442186] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.457636] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   10.457649] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   10.457654] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   10.457756] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[   10.775316] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.775329] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.775342] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

systemctl:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-12-01 06:48:14 UTC; 39min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 693 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─693 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap
```

/var/log/debug:

```
./debug:213:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
./debug:214:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DiscoverableTimeout'
./debug:215:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'PairableTimeout'
./debug:216:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'AutoConnectTimeout'
./debug:217:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Name'
./debug:218:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Class'
./debug:219:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID'
./debug:220:Dec  1 05:16:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[6571]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'ReverseServiceDiscovery'
```

I am using bluetooth V5.23, dbus V1.8.20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Paired successfully, but this device has 
no services which can be used with Raspberry Pi
```

Seems reasonably clear. To expand [source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/):-

> Bluetooth support is limited at this stage; you can pair with pretty much anything, but you can only usefully connect to devices which support either the Human Interface Device or Audio Sink services – in other words, mice, keyboards and other UI devices, and speakers and headsets.

Comment: No wonder why. I have been up to solve this issue for a day. 
Can I send simple numbers over bluetooth after pair but not connected?
To have a full connection, I better go get bluetooth dongle. Thank you :)

Comment: Any chance this will change in the near future? I'd love to know where to start to see if I could help fix it, but don't know anything about Bluetooth yet. My use case is I want to have my Android app talk to my RPi 3B over its native Bluetooth. I'll use wifi for now, but would prefer BT.

Comment: Apologies, this should be a comment but I don't have enough points for that...
As of today, accepted answer still seems to stand; Raspberry Pi BLE only works with HID and audio profiles. I spent hours trying to figure out why it would disconnect as soon as it connected to my ESP32 board which connects fine to other devices. Troubleshooting was compounded by receiving many different messages in btmon. Then in one configuration saw message "connection failed - no usable services on this device", and found a reference to this page. It still seems to apply...

Answer (score 1):

Install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth blueman
```

Make sure to reboot pi after this installation.
Now on your raspberry pi console, click on Bluetooth -> add your device and check by sending your files.